# How to center a text relative to another text using css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I am building a **scorecard** which will show some scores of different parameters of your health. Here is my code below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Scorecard</title>
    <style>
        .sub-score {
            margin-left: 20%;
            color: #00FF00;

        }

        .category {
            color: DodgerBlue;
        }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br>

        <div>
            <h1 style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color: #FA0066;">SCORE</h1>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:10%">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
                <h3 class="category">Sugar Level</h3>
                <h2 class="sub-score">46<h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 
                <h3 class="category">Hemoglobin Level</h3>
                <h2 class="sub-score">82<h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 
                <h3 class="category">Water</h3>
                <h2 class="sub-score">46<h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 
                <h3 class="category">Blood Pressure</h3>
                <h2 class="sub-score">54<h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"> 
                <h3 class="category">Security</h3>
                <h2 class="sub-score">46<h2>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Here is how it looks like in the browser

[image]

As you can see there are different health parameters such has `Sugar level`, `Hemoglobin level` etc. But if you observe carefully, the scores aren't in center to their respective parameters especially for `Water` and `Security`. Now I am not sure how do I center it with respect to the parameter above the scores.

I read about positions in css such as `relative` and `absolute` but I am not sure how do I use it with respect to another element. I also tried `display: flex; align-items: center;` to the `sub-score` div but to no avail.

How can I position the numbers with respect to the parameters?

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap3 , you may keep on floatting elements, add an extra container in between cols and contents. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbMepV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually found the solution while you stylized the main h1. it just needs a little more approach. `content-justify` : `center`.

### Method 1

> I'm writing this method because, you are using flex with bootstrap 3. So
>   you can switch to 4. [See also.](https://getbootstrap.com)

```css
.sub-score {
  color: #00FF00;
}

.category {
  color: DodgerBlue;
}

.center {
  display: flex!important;
  align-items: center!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <br>

  <div>
    <h1 class="center">SCORE</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 column center">
      <h3 class="category">Sugar Level</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">46
        <h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 column center">
      <h3 class="category">Hemoglobin Level</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">82
        <h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 column center">
      <h3 class="category">Water</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">46
        <h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 column center">
      <h3 class="category">Blood Pressure</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">54
        <h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 column center">
      <h3 class="category">Security</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">46
        <h2>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

### Method 2

```css
.sub-score {
  color: #00FF00;
}

.category {
  color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <br>

  <div>
    <h1 class="text-center">SCORE</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <h3 class="category">Sugar Level</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">46
        <h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <h3 class="category">Hemoglobin Level</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">82
        <h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <h3 class="category">Water</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score ">46
        <h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <h3 class="category">Blood Pressure</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">54
        <h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <h3 class="category">Security</h3>
      <h2 class="sub-score">46
        <h2>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

`text-center` bootstrap 3 [helper classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type-alignment).

Comment: migration to bootstrap4 could also be a good option ;) with a link to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/ to help update classes if necessary

Comment: So yes, I saw that the friend used the flex for `h1`. It would make sense to produce a solution in the same way :)

Comment: @G-Cyr, & Souvik-Ray in fact yes would be the most healthy 4 pass.

Comment: @SouvikRay You are welcome. I'm update my answer with more details, please visit.

Comment: Meanwhile thanks to @G-Cyr for the contribution of version 4.

Answer (score 1):

Copy below code in blank html file and open it in your browser. You will get your desired output.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Scorecard</title>
  <style>
    .sub-score {
      text-align: center;
      color: #00FF00;
    }

    .category {
      text-align: center;
      color: DodgerBlue;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <br>

    <div>
      <h1 style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color: #FA0066;">SCORE</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:10%">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <h3 class="category">Sugar Level</h3>
        <h2 class="sub-score">46
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
        <h3 class="category">Hemoglobin Level</h3>
        <h2 class="sub-score">82
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <h3 class="category">Water</h3>
        <h2 class="sub-score">46
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <h3 class="category">Blood Pressure</h3>
        <h2 class="sub-score">54
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
        <h3 class="category">Security</h3>
        <h2 class="sub-score">46
        </h2>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `text-align: center;` on the `<h2>` and `<h3>` to center the text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text-center` bootstrap class to align your elements at the center

Sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gladiatoriitoo/fvjztu6x/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Html tables are great for this purpose:

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <th><h3 class="category">Sugar Level</h3></th>
    <th><h3 class="category">Hemoglobin Level</h3></th>
    <th><h3 class="category">Water</h3></th>
    <th><h3 class="category">Blood Pressure</h3></th>
    <th><h3 class="category">Security</h3></th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><h2 class="sub-score">46</h2></td>
    <td><h2 class="sub-score">82</h2></td>
    <td><h2 class="sub-score">46</h2></td>
    <td><h2 class="sub-score">54</h2></td>
    <td><h2 class="sub-score">46</h2></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

You can then use CSS to style the table's padding and margin the way you like. It will be consistent to all cells.

Note that using `H2` and `H3` this way is not 'SEO-friendly', you may like to put that text inside a span or such. But it is ok if you are just testing.

Comment: He is have an responsive tree. Idea of table nice, but don't responsive.

Comment: with a table, you may also turn td into th and drop the hx tags which become useless at this point where the table-layout describes and link structure and contents  ;)